# Проблема с установкой библиотеку aiogramm

Tags: python

Помогите как решить эту проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел ссылку на установку библиотеки: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/install.html с примером:

```
pip install -U aiogram
```

И понял, что у вас опечатка в названии библиотеки